# Use regular expressions to extract and display Interface and method status for all the interfaces using Python

Tags: python

I want to extract the Interface , Status and Protocol column from the below show output using Python Regular Expression ..Please help

Below is the output of `# show ip interface brief command` on a router

```
Interface       IP-Address  OK?     Method Status   Protocol

FastEthernet0/0 192.168.1.242   YES     manual up   up 
FastEthernet1/0        unassigned   YES     unset       down 
Serial2/0               192.168.1.250   YES     manual up   up 
Serial3/0               192.168.1.233   YES     manual up   up 
FastEthernet4/0        unassigned   YES     unset       down    
FastEthernet5/0        unassigned   YES        unset        down
```

I want to use regular expressions to extract and display Interface and method status for all the interfaces.

```
FastEthernet0/0, manual up
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You can improve your question by hitting the 'edit' link at the bottom of the post. You may also find this useful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).... The excellent [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) has Python flavours and is a great way to troubleshoot problematic regex.

Answer (score 0):

you may do it as below: I would prefer split instead of regex due to uneven column length.

```
output = """
Interface       IP-Address  OK?     Method Status   Protocol

FastEthernet0/0 192.168.1.242   YES     manual up   up
FastEthernet1/0        unassigned   YES     unset       down
Serial2/0               192.168.1.250   YES     manual up   up
Serial3/0               192.168.1.233   YES     manual up   up
FastEthernet4/0        unassigned   YES     unset       down
FastEthernet5/0        unassigned   YES        unset        down
"""
import re
parsed_data = dict()

for line in output.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()

    if line == '' or not (line.startswith('Fast') or line.startswith('Serial')):
        continue

    # replace multiple space with one
    line = re.sub('\s+', ' ', line)
    data = line.split(' ')
    if len(data) == 5:
        parsed_data[data[0]] = (data[0], data[3], None)
    else:
        parsed_data[data[0]] = (data[0], data[3], data[4])

for key in parsed_data.keys():
    print parsed_data[key][0], parsed_data[key][1], parsed_data[key][2]
```

Output:

```
FastEthernet1/0 unset None
Serial3/0 manual up
FastEthernet5/0 unset None
FastEthernet0/0 manual up
Serial2/0 manual up
FastEthernet4/0 unset None
```

with regex:

```
import re
parsed_data = dict()

for line in output.split('\n'):
    reobj = re.search('((Fast|Serial)\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', line)
    if reobj:
        intf = reobj.group(1)
        if reobj.group(3) == 'unset':
            parsed_data[intf] = (intf, reobj.group(3), None)
        else:
            parsed_data[intf] = (intf, reobj.group(3), reobj.group(4))

for key in parsed_data.keys():
    print parsed_data[key][0], parsed_data[key][1], parsed_data[key][2]
```